# Unable to Commit Changes to Git in Android Studio 1.0.2

Tags: android, git, version-control, commit

I am using Android Studio 1.0.2 with Git on Windows 8.1 (64 Bit). I have a local Git Repository which is being pushed to BitBucket online.

The VCS seems to work fine in, until I ask it to commit my changes. In The commit changes windows I can see the files that have changed . However in the "Details" section I see "fatal: Path "some/path" exists on disk, but not in 'some-hash'.

If I use GitBash to commit changes, it works fine. I can even push changes to remote server.

I hope someone here can help. I don't want to go through commands when this can be done through UI.

Comment: what is the exact message in details?

Comment: I get this in the commit window:
fatal: Path 'ProjectName/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' exists on disk, but not in '2ac999....'

I get this if I click the "Commit" button:
An alert "Commit failed with an error"

The error in Messages window says:
Error:error: pathspec 'ProjectName/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' did not match any file(s) known to git.
 during executing git commit --only -F C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\git-commit-msg-1734650703657568967.txt -- ProjectName/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: for some reason the return keys are stripped when I add a comment. Sorry if it is hard to read.